# Finding distinct elements in a list

Tags: python, list, time-complexity, distinct

Given a list like this, where first column is the id and second is a string,

```
x = [ [1, ["cat","dog"]],
      [2, ["dog", "mouse", "elephant"]],
      [3, ["mouse", "giraffe"]] ]
```

I would like to know a way to efficiently group up all the distinct elements into another list.

My problem comes in because there is a complexity requirement that I have to meet.

O(UCK), where U is the number of items in the list, C is the maximum number of characters in any animal, K is the maximum amount of animals in a list.

Example output:

```
[ ["cat"],
  ["dog"],
  ["mouse"],
  ["elephant"],
  ["giraffe"] ]
```

My solution used a dictionary to do this:

```
distinctList = []
distinctDict = {}
for item in x:
     for animal in item[1]:
         if animal not in distinctDict:
              distinctList.append(animal)
              distinctDict[animal] = 1
```

However the complexity for this would become O(UKN), where N is the number of items in the dictionary. This complexity is larger than the required complexity.

Comment: do you really need a list of list of strings? or did you mean `["cat", "dog", "mouse", "elephant", "giraffe"]`

Comment: doesnt have to be a list of list of strings. it can be that also. i think i found a solution, what i did was append all the animals from x into a newList. then i did unique = list(set(newList)).. this gives me a list of unique animals. does this meet the complexity requirement?

Comment: @avigil sorry im abit weak on analysis of algorithms

Answer (score 4):

You can do that with a set comprehension like:

#### Code:

```
uniques = {animal for row in data for animal in row[1]}
```

#### Test Code:

```
data = [[1, ["cat", "dog"]],
        [2, ["dog", "mouse", "elephant"]],
        [3, ["mouse", "giraffe"]]]

uniques = {animal for row in data for animal in row[1]}
print(uniques)
```

#### Results:

```
{'cat', 'giraffe', 'mouse', 'dog', 'elephant'}
```

Comment: if OP is worried about complexity he can check the wiki page on [time complexity for common python structures](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)

Comment: @avigil what is the complexity of this tho? i cant seem to figure it out

Comment: It is only going to visit each element once.  And the set creation is going to be build the index on the fly.  But I don't know exactly how it will map to O.

Comment: `for row in data` is your `U`, `for animal in row` is your `K`, and setting a value in a set is amortized constant (but worst case N). So in this case its O(UK) for the average case, but O(UKN) worst case (where the hash function used to determine set membership spits out a constant value that always creates a collision). Realistically, the hash for strings is pretty efficient so it should be closer to O(UK)

Answer (score 0):

This returns a nested list just like your example output is a nested list.

```
#!python2

x = [[1, ["cat", "dog"]], [2, ["dog", "mouse", "elephant"]], [3, ["mouse", "giraffe"]]]
new_lst = []

for sublst in x:
    for subsublst in sublst[1]:
        if not any(subsublst in sublst for sublst in new_lst):
            new_lst.append([subsublst]) # nested list
            # new_lst.append(subsublst) # a list of strings
print new_lst

'''
[['cat'], ['dog'], ['mouse'], ['elephant'], ['giraffe']]
'''
```

Comment: isn't this bigger than the required complexity? this come out to O(U^2 K)

Answer (score 0):

```
In [126]: data = [[1, ["cat", "dog"]],
     ...:         [2, ["dog", "mouse", "elephant"]],
     ...:         [3, ["mouse", "giraffe"]]]       

In [127]: [[x] for x in {animal for row in data for animal in row[1]}]
Out[127]: [['giraffe'], ['mouse'], ['elephant'], ['cat'], ['dog']]
```